# File read access from threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have a static class that contains a number of functions that read values from configuration files. The configuration files are provided with the software and the software itself NEVER writes to them.

I have a number of threads that are running in my application and I need to call a function in the static class. The function will then go to one of the configuration files, look up a value (depending on the parameter that I pass when I call the function) and then return a result.

I need the threads to be able to read the file all at the same time (or rather, without synchronising to the main thread). The threads will NEVER write to the configuration files.

My question is simply, therefore, will there be any issues in allowing multiple threads to call the same static functions to read values from the same file at the same time? I can appreciate that there would be serialization issues if some threads were writing to the file while others were reading, but this will never happen.

Basically:
1. Are there any issues allowing multiple threads to read from the same file at the same time?
2. Are there any issues allowing multiple threads to call the same static functions (in the same static class) at the same time?

Comment: Just a remark.. You might want to write a wrapper class for the configuration that keeps the configuration in memory instead of reading the configuration over and over from the file. In the end it'll be a lot nicer when the reading of the file is encapsulated inside such  a class.

Comment: The configuration file contains hundreds of lines of information. I pass a value into a function that reads the file and returns configuration information relating to the value that I passed in. I think it's less memory intensive to read the file every now and again rather than store the whole thing in memory, given that I don't need all of the information all of the time.

Comment: In general I appreciate the fact that you strive to create optimized software, but you work on Delphi software, which usually means that your code is already more than a decade old, and it'll run for yet another decade. You can get 24GB for less than €80 today, so better think twice before you sacrifice maintainability of your software to save some kilobytes of RAM.

Comment: I agree with your point, but the application is pretty processor intensive and we have to bear in mind that some of our customers are running it on very low specced PCs, so in this case it makes more sense to have an overhead on the i/o operations than reading lots of unecessary information into memory which would likely have a knock on effect on a large portion of our customer base. Thanks for the response, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this CAN be an issue, depending on how the class is actually locating and reading from the files, and more so if the class is also caching the values so it does not need to read from the files every time.  Without seeing your class's actual code, there is no way to tell you whether your code is thread-safe or not.

Comment: OK, so basically, the file that I'm currently dealing with contains a few hundred lines of information, each line broken down into several sections. I have a function in a static class that I call, passing a parameter in. The function opens the file, reads it until it comes to the value that I passed into the function and then returns configuration information relating to that value (basically the contents of the line). As the function doesn't write anything to the file, and as nothing is being cached, would there be an issue with multiple threads calling the same function?

Comment: If the function is re-opening the file, reading the relevant data from it, and then closing the file before exiting (which in of itself if not a very efficient model for file I/O), then that is generally thread-safe as long as the function is using a local variable for the file handle/pointer.  Each access to the file would be using a different file handle/pointer to access the data, and that would be thread-safe.

Comment: Just as I thought (although I had a few doubts). Thanks for the confirmation!